# Generar código en Python que de el valor máximo y sus posiciones

Tags: python

Hola me podrían ayudar a terminar mi código me piden la
posición o posiciones que ocupa el valor máximo del arreglo.

```
def maximo(valores):

    mayor = valores[0]

    for i in range (1, len(valores)):

        if valores[i] > mayor:

            mayor= valores [i]
       
    return mayor


numeros = [16, 7, 86, 92, 13, -8, 92]

print (maximo(numeros))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en que lenguaje sera esto??? codigo abierto, no suena a una etiqueta valida para tu problema.. usa el boton [edit] y arregla todo. de paso, tu valor esta en i ;)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo tienes que agregar las líneas que definen los índices y su impresión; tal como se encuentra a continuación:

```
def maximo(valores):

    mayor = valores[0]

    for i in range (1, len(valores)):

        if valores[i] > mayor:

            mayor= valores [i]
       
    return mayor


numeros = [16, 7, 86, 92, 13, -8, 92]

max = maximo(numeros)

indices = [ i for i, ele in enumerate(numeros) if max == ele ]

print("El maximo {} esta en las posiciones:".format(max))
print(indices)
```

La salida de ejecución del código anterior es la siguiente:

```
El maximo 92 esta en las posiciones:
[3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo, con diccionarios, es usando el valor de cada elemento como índice del diccionario y las posiciones como valor, asi: `{elem1:[pos1], elem2:[pos1, pos2], ...}`

Viéndolo en la consola

```
>>> numeros = [16, 7, 86, 92, 13, -8, 92]
>>> d = {}
>>> for idx, value in enumerate(numeros):
        d.setdefault(value, []).append(idx)
```

[*] Documentación [dic.setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
Hasta este punto, `d` será: `{-8: [5], 7: [1], 13: [4], 16: [0], 86: [2], 92: [3, 6]}`

Ahora es solo ubicar el valor del máximo índice del diccionario:

```
>>> d[max(d.keys())]
[3, 6]
```